# Roboearth DBException API

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to use the RoboEarth API through the website, or using the object Model Downloader as detailed in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection).

I get a database exception error as detailed below.

> DBException at /objects/result 'Hbase
> connection failed: Could not connect
> to pcube:9090'
>
> [ INFO] [1396359404.695247797]:
> SearchObjects (UID: videogame.kinectadventures): Failed

This happen whether I am logged in or not, so I assume it is a general issue.
Is there someone I should alert to this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147006/roboearth-dbexception-api/) by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The database is back up now.

If anyone knows why it was down, or who to alert next time it goes down that would be really helpful.

---

Originally posted by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) with karma: 80 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0